# Polynomial time algorithm to solve the TSP on an m by n solid grid

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms

Is there a polynomial algorithm to solve TSP (or Ham Cycle) on an m by n solid grid graph whose points are at unit distance apart? I've heard about Umans and Lenhart research paper but reading such paper is beyond my capability.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve on solid grid graphs ? Hamiltonian Cycle ?

Comment: @Shiva, Yes, Hamiltonian Cycle, Travelling Salesman.

Comment: Could you please edit the question (and the title)?

Comment: What is “m by n solid grid graph”?  If it means the m×n grid graph with mn vertices, then it is straightforward to see that the Hamiltonian Cycle problem on such graphs is in P.

Comment: even if it's beyond you to read the paper, doesn't the abstract answer your question? http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/SFCS.1997.646138

Answer (score 2):

This paper is more general than what you're asking for, but should lead you to some answers.  It's pretty accessible too:

http://research.cs.queensu.ca/home/yurai/Publications/Hamilt%20of%20thin%20solid%20and%20hard%20grids.pdf

(Though looking at it now the primary reference I'd have suggested out of that would be the Umans and Lenhart paper...)